# iOS: Access 'Scan QR Code' feature on Chrome for iOS from a Web app

Tags: ios, qr-code, chrome-ios

I want to scan a QR code from a Web App on browser of a Mobile Device. Now, I am using the `getUserMedia` API to get the video stream and a JS library for decoding which works perfectly for chrome on Android but not on iOS, since iOS DOESN'T support getUserMedia API.

I read [here](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/02/02/google-chrome-ios-update-qr-code/) that Chrome for iOS now comes with in-built QR code scanner. This might just resolve my issue, if I can access the functionality through some JavaScript API like navigator object or so.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

I know there is a work around to use `<input type="file" accept="image/*">` to capture image and then decode it. But this has higher chances of decode failure and not a good UX.